# Does deploying with Heroku change how I should approach security?

Tags: heroku, security

Does deploying with Heroku change any of the best security practices I should follow in creating a webapp in general?

For instance some recommendations from [Yahoo](http://developer.yahoo.com/security/#application):

- hashing and salt passwords
- safe cookie management
- checking arguments passed to database

Comment: It changes none of the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes nothing, not much else to say.